# Getting node.js and grunt to run on Vagrant box (ubuntu-precise12042-x64-vbox43)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vagrant, node.js, puppet

I am having trouble understanding how I would get node.js, Grunt and NPM to run on my Vagrant box. I am using the ubuntu-precise12042-x64-vbox43 and provisioning it through puppet. I am just getting started with puppet so I went to https://puphpet.com to generate a manifest. After `vagrant up` the box provisioned as it should and all is up and running without a problem. 
I then google around to find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19000534/install-node-js-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-using-puppet. I ran `vagrant SSH` and after that I ran `puppet module install willdurand/nodejs` which ran fine. Now is the problem that I don´t know what to do next? I thought I would be able to run NPM and Node commands while "in" `vagrant SSH`. What am i doing wrong? If I run just `NPM`it says:

`the program 'npm' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install npm`

Do I have to run some other command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just installing the puppet module doesn't install the program, it just tells puppet how to deal with nodejs in puppet. You need to add a declaration to your puppet manifest and run `vagrant provision` again.

Example:

```
class { 'nodejs':
  version => 'stable',
}

package { 'express':
  provider => npm
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Vagrantfile` define your provisioning file:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "scripts/provision.sh"
```

Then create `package.json` for `npm` with required packages (e.g. `grunt`) like:

```
{
  "name": "vagrant",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-cli": "^0.1.13",
    "grunt-exec": "^0.4.6",
    "shelljs": "^0.5.3"
  }
}
```

Then in `provision.sh` install `npm` and dependent packages via:

```
apt-get install
npm install
grunt --version
```

and see if that would work during the VM provisioning (`vagrant up`).

Or use the Puppet manifest as described in the other answer.